# Вывод категорий и подкатегорий

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Правильно ли я сделал вывод?

```
<?php 

    $host = 'localhost';
    $db = 'test';
    $user = 'root';
    $pass = '';
    $charset = 'utf8';
    $dsn = "mysql:host=$host; dbname=$db;charset=$charset";
    $opt = [
        PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
        PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
        PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES   => false,
        ];

    $pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass, $opt);

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `category`";

    $res = $pdo->query($sql)->fetchAll();

    echo '<ul>';
        foreach($res as $key => $val) {
            $subCat = "SELECT * FROM sub_category WHERE category_id = " . $val['id'];
            $result = $pdo->query($subCat)->fetchAll();

            echo '<li>';
                echo '<a href="cat-'.$val['id'].'">'.$val['name']. '</a>';

                echo '<ul>';
                foreach($result as $k => $v) {
                    echo '<li><a href="sub-'.$v['id'].'">' . $v['name'] . '</a></li>';
                }
                echo '</ul>';
            echo '</li>';
        }
    echo '</ul>';
```

Для каждой категории, сделал отельный запрос, на подкатегорию, это правильный подход?

Если сделать запрос на категории и подкатегории

```
SELECT category.id, category.name, sub_category.name
    FROM category LEFT JOIN sub_category
    ON sub_category.category_id = category.id
```

То получится вот такое

```
1 Программы Антивирусы
1 Программы Запись
1 Программы Интернет
1 Программы Аудио
2 Фильмы Боевики
2 Фильмы Фантастика
2 Фильмы Ужастики
```

И такой массив с массивами, будет сложнее вывести.

Comment: прям так сложнее? тем более `PDO::FETCH_GROUP` вам половину работы сделает.

Comment: он хорошо делает группировку, но в нём нету самой категории

Comment: $sql = "SELECT category.name, category.id as catId, sub_category.name, sub_category.id
    FROM category LEFT JOIN sub_category
    ON sub_category.category_id = category.id";
 
 $res = $pdo->query($sql)->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_GROUP);
 
 echo '<ul>';
 foreach($res as $key => $val) {
  echo '<li><a href="/cat='.$val[0]['catId'].'">'.$key. '</a><ul>';
   foreach($val as $k => $v) {
    echo '<li><a href="sub-'.$v['id'].'">' . $v['name'] . '</a></li>';
   }
  echo '</ul></li>';
 }
 echo '</ul>';

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Писать надо определенно один запрос. А если не один, то использовать подготовленные запросы и передавать параметры туда как следует.

PDO в принципе и сам умеет группировать, хот такая группировка и не очень функциональна.  Ваш код будет выглядеть примерно так (*не проверено*):

```
$st = $dbh->query("SELECT c.id, c.name
                         ,s.id as sub_id, s.name as sub_name
                   FROM category AS c
                   LEFT JOIN sub_category AS s ON (s.category_id = c.id)");

$categories = $st->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC | PDO::FETCH_GROUP);

echo '<ul>';
foreach($categories as $cId => $data) {

    echo '<li>';
    echo '<a href="cat-'.$cId.'">'.$data[0]['name']. '</a>';

    echo '<ul>';
    foreach($data as $sub) {
        echo '<li><a href="sub-'.$sub['sub_id'].'">' . $sub['sub_name'] . '</a></li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
    echo '</li>';
}
echo '</ul>';
```

Но и самому такую группировку сделать весьма просто:
исходные

```
$data = [
        ['id' => 1, 'name' => 'Программы', 'sub_id' => 1, 'sub_name' => "Антивирусы"],
        ['id' => 1, 'name' => 'Программы', 'sub_id' => 2, 'sub_name' => "Запись"],
        ['id' => 1, 'name' => 'Программы', 'sub_id' => 3, 'sub_name' => "Интернет"],
        ['id' => 1, 'name' => 'Программы', 'sub_id' => 4, 'sub_name' => "Аудио"],
        ['id' => 2, 'name' => 'Фильмы',    'sub_id' => 5, 'sub_name' => "Боевики"],
        ['id' => 2, 'name' => 'Фильмы',    'sub_id' => 6, 'sub_name' => "Фантастика"],
        ['id' => 2, 'name' => 'Фильмы',    'sub_id' => 7, 'sub_name' => "Ужастики"]
    ];
```

группировка

```
$result = [];
$cId = null;
foreach($data as $d){
    if($d['id'] != $cId) {
        $cId = $d['id'];
        $result[$cId] = ['id' => $d['id'], 'name' => $d['name'], 'sub' => [] ];
    }

    $result[$cId]['sub'][] = ['id' => $d['sub_id'], 'name' => $d['sub_name']];
}

print_r($result);
```

Comment: Я сделал чуть по другому $sql = "SELECT category.name, category.id as catId, sub_category.name, sub_category.id
    FROM category LEFT JOIN sub_category
    ON sub_category.category_id = category.id";
 
 $res = $pdo->query($sql)->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_GROUP);
 
 echo '<ul>';
 foreach($res as $key => $val) {
  echo '<li><a href="/cat='.$val[0]['catId'].'">'.$key. '</a><ul>';
   foreach($val as $k => $v) {
    echo '<li><a href="sub-'.$v['id'].'">' . $v['name'] . '</a></li>';
   }
  echo '</ul></li>';
 }
 echo '</ul>';

Comment: Ох точно, `ORDER BY c.id`, конечно, обязателен

Comment: почему обязателен?

Comment: @DivMan эт для моего решения. оно основано на том, что категории идут последовательно. а без order by никто этого не гарантирует.

Answer (score 1):

Почти всегда лучше делать один запрос. Только в запросе не забыть про сортировку

```
$pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass, $opt);

$sql = "SELECT
    category.id, category.name,
    sub_category.id sub_id, sub_category.name sub_name
  FROM category LEFT JOIN sub_category
  ON sub_category.category_id = category.id
  ORDER BY sub_category.category_id";

$res = $pdo->query($sql)->fetchAll();

echo '<ul>';
$old_id = null;
foreach($res as $key => $val) {
  if ($val['id'] !== $old_id) {
    if (isset($old_id))
      echo '</ul></li>';
    $old_id = $val['id'];
    echo '<li>';
    echo '<a href="cat-'.$val['id'].'">'.$val['name']. '</a>';
    echo '<ul>';
  }
  if (isset($val['sub_id']))
    echo '<li><a href="sub-'.$val['sub_id'].'">' . $val['sub_name'] . '</a></li>';
}
if (isset($old_id))
  echo '</ul></li>';
echo '</ul>';
```

Ну и на будущее: писать `SELECT *` плохо всегда. Даже если Вам нужно выбрать 50 полей. **Всегда** указывайте имена нужных Вам полей